# WhenEvent "StopIntegration" problem

Tags: differential-equations

The first example on the WhenEvent help page is

```
NDSolve[{y''[t] == -9.81, y[0] == 5, y'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> -0.95 y'[t]]}, y, {t, 0, 10}];
```

Say I want to stop the integration at the first bounce, I would put

```
NDSolve[{y''[t] == -9.81, y[0] == 5, y'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[y[t] == 0,"StopIntegration"]}, y, {t, 0, 10}];
```

That, however, does not stop the integration (i.e. it goes on to t=10), neither does the condition y[t] < 0.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
ySol = NDSolveValue[{y''[t] == -9.81, y[0] == 5, y'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, {tMax = t, "StopIntegration"}]}, 
  y, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[ySol[x], {x, 0, tMax}]
```

And in `tMax` you'll get `1.00964`, that's slightly larger than `t` when `y[t] = 0`.

[image: plot]

Comment: great, that works!

Comment: @jacob You're code works too, I think you just want to plot to `10` and it will plot, because it's an `InterpolationFunction` and can plot outside the defined range.

Comment: ok thanks, that's what was confusing me